# Is it possible to sort a table column based on a month in griddle

Tags: reactjs, sorting, griddle

I have a timestamp returned like this:

Fri Jun 30 2017 09:57:18 GMT+0100 (BST)

and I formatted it to look like this : 
Jun 30, Fri 2017 09:57

When it is sorted in the Griddle it is sorted alphabetically
(apr,aug,dec,feb,jan,jul,jun,mar,may,nov,oct,sep) as it should but I really want to have them sorted according to months.

sortType: 'date' in metacolumns does not work.

```
return (<Griddle results={lRowData}
            columns={this.columns()}
            columnMetadata={this.columnMetadata()}
            initialSort="date"
            resultsPerPage={20}/>
        );
},
columns() {
    const lColumns = ['date'];
    return lColumns;
},
columnMetadata() {
    const lColumnMetadata = [{
        columnName: 'date',
        displayName: 'Date'
    }];
    return lColumnMetadata;
}
```

Is there a way to use some kind of indexed table like:

`allMonths = ['Jan' , 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May',...., 'Dec']` where will be the one that helps on sorting them ?

Answer (score 0):

For Griddle v0.x, check out `customCompareFn` ([docs](https://griddlegriddle.github.io/v0-docs/customization.html)), e.g.

```
const allMonths = ['Jan', 'Feb', ...];
const lColumnMetadata = [{
    columnName: 'date',
    customCompareFn: date => allMonths.indexOf(date.substring(0, 3)),
    displayName: 'Date'
}];
```